# ASP.NET putting a control in a C# <%= Function(<control/>) %>

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I know you can't put a control inside a C# function like this

```
<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(<umbraco:Item field="background" runat="server" />) %>
```

but I am wondering if you can pass the value from a control to a C# function.
umbraco:Item above outputs something like ~/media/bg1.jpg

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="/masterpages/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<asp:content ContentPlaceHolderId="cphHead" runat="server">
  <style type="text/css">
    #content {
      background: url('<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(<umbraco:Item field="background" runat="server" />)%>');
    }
  </style>
</asp:content>
```

Anyone know any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't explained what you are trying to do. The `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute` method takes a string (a virtual path). What is the relationship between the Umbraco Item control and a virtual path? A control can be placed in any page and can therefore have any virtual path. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained that. umbraco:Item will output something like ~/media/bg1.jpg which is the background for the page you're on. I am trying to pass that value to the VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute function. Not possible is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just a plain textstring then you can do the following:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="/masterpages/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="umbraco" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="umbraco.presentation" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory" %>
<asp:content ContentPlaceHolderId="cphHead" runat="server">
  <style type="text/css">
    #content {
      background: url('<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(Node.GetCurrent().GetProperty("background").Value)%>');
    }
  </style>
</asp:content>
```

However, if the "background" property is a media picker then you need a little more help than just that, which will involve the umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media namespace. I suggest you check out the libraries with Reflector, or the source code repository on Codeplex to find out the classes you should be using and how to subsequently populate your property.

HTH,

Benjamin

Comment: Wow! Not the solution I expected, but it works! Thanks a lot Benjamin!